# Quantum Mechanics - Derivation of the fact that determinate states are eigenvectors of the $\hat{Q}$ operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, wavefunction, eigenvalue

In the *Intro to Quantum Mechanics* textbook by Griffiths on page 105 equation [3.116], I'm confused about 3 things.

[image]

1. What is $$\hat{Q}$$ supposed to represent? At first they use the variance definition but then they treat it as an operator. In fact, if they really used the variance definition, it should have just been denoted with Q, not with the extra hat on top.
2. How did they get from $$\langle(\hat{Q} - \langle Q\rangle)^{2}\rangle$$ to $$\langle\Psi|\langle(\hat{Q} - \langle Q\rangle)^{2}\Psi\rangle$$
3. Why is $$(\hat{Q} - \langle Q\rangle)$$ a Hermitian operator? (I understand that it's an operator)

Comment: *What is $\hat{Q}$ supposed to represent?* The quantum operator corresponding to an arbitrary observable physical quantity, such as position, momentum, angular momentum, energy, dipole moment, etc.

Comment: Please only ask one question per post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. $Q$ is an observable quantity (position, momentum *etc.*). This observable is represented by a Hermitian operator $\hat{Q}$.

At the microscopic level particles don't have a definite state, they present a superposition of states. This is why linear combinations are used in QM to model particles's states. In this context one should not be surpised to find operators, *i.e.* linear maps, acting on states. At this point, you need to be a little familiar with linear algebra and in particular with eigenvectors and eigenvalues. Among operators some are said to be Hermitian. Two key results for any Hermitian operator $\hat{Q}$ are:

(i) All its eigenvalues are real.
(ii) Its eigenvectors (also called eigenstates in this context) form a basis of the space, meaning that any state of our space can be written as a linear combination of these eigenvectors.

Now, assume one has a Hermitian operator denoted $\hat{x}$ whose eigenstates are $|x\rangle$, where $x$ is a real variable. The state $|x\rangle$ denotes the eigenstate with eigenvalue $x$, *i.e.* $\hat{x} |x\rangle = x |x\rangle$. Since the eigenstates of $\hat{x}$ form a basis, all you need to know about $\hat{x}$ is how it acts on its eigenstates. According to the equation above, in this basis $\hat{x}$ is represented by $x$, *i.e.* the action of $\hat{x}$ is simply given by the multiplication by $x$. As a consequence, the operator $\hat{x}$ is used for representing position.

In general, identical measurements on a system in the same state do not yield the same results, so one should not confuse $\hat{Q}$ with its expectation value $\langle Q\rangle$.

2. It is simply the definition of the expectation value of $\hat{Q}$ in the state $|\Psi\rangle$.
3. Assuming $\hat{Q}$ is Hermitian, then the operator $\hat{Q} - \langle Q\rangle$ is also Hermitian. Indeed, it is easy to check that
   $$\langle \phi|(\hat{Q} - \langle Q\rangle)|\psi\rangle =  (\langle \psi|(\hat{Q} - \langle Q\rangle)|\phi\rangle)^*$$
   for all states $|\phi\rangle$, $|\psi\rangle$.

Comment: 2. and 3. make sense to me now, thank you. I'm still confused about 1. on a deeper level. What exactly do you mean by Q is represented by $$\hat{Q}$$? Specifically, in $$\langle(\hat{Q} - \langle Q\rangle)^{2}\rangle$$, why didn't they just use either $$\hat{Q}$$ or Q only? (i.e. why use a combination of $$\hat{Q}$$ and Q, if you can just one notation or the other, since they both represent the same thing, apparently?)

Comment: I added some details for 1.

Comment: @dnie please don't forget to like or accept the answer (or both :) ) if you're satisfied.